# Claudia fail to configure access credentials

Tags: node.js, facebook, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to build a facebook bot using claudia, by following this [guide](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/installing.html), I was told to:

1. Create an AWS profile with IAM full access, Lambda full access and API Gateway Administrator privileges.
2. Add the keys to your .aws/credentials file

However I cannot find either 'aws' folder or 'credentials' file on my mac.

Some people say I can find it at `~/.aws/credentials`, but it's not working as well.

Please help with this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the AWS CLI (Command Line Interface) tool unless you already have it installed. Since you are using a Mac, you can do that using Homebrew, e.g. `$ brew install awscli`. Next, you can execute the [configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/) command, e.g.

```
$ aws configure
```

When prompted, you enter AWS credentials (AWS access key id and AWS secret access key) and some default configuration. As a result, the `~/.aws/credentials` and the `~/.aws/config` files will [be created](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-config-files).

See also the AWS CLI [getting started guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/).

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!